# Sql Server make stored proc show select and run other proc on select's results

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to make a stored procedure that will be called form a web method. The basic idea is the proc needs to

1. Check if there will be a result to the query `(IF EXISTS ...)`
2. If there is a result, return one row with an ID value the webmethod
   will use
3. Call another stored proc using that same ID as a
   parameter (this proc will then update the record the first proc took
   the ID from and increase the value of one of it's column's).

So far I have

```
CREATE PROC Sponsors.GetLightBoxAds (@SponsorID varchar(30))
AS
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1
      AD.ADID
    FROM Sponsors.AD
    WHERE AD.Active = 1 and AD.Sponsor = @SponsorID)
  --takes the ID value of first active AD record it finds, at random, for that sponsor
  BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1
      AD.ADID --I want to use this value as my parameter for the second proc.
    FROM Sponsors.AD
    WHERE AD.Active = 1 
    ORDER BY newid()
    --Ideally I'd like to call a separate proc here because there's more to be done 
    --but for testing I'm trying to run the update here
    UPDATE Sponsor.AD
    SET AD.CurrentClickCount = AD.CurrentClickCount + 1
    WHERE ADID = @ADID -- use the result of the first select here.
  END
END
GO
```

Is there a way to make the proc both return the ID I wanted and call another proc using that ID as the call's parameter?

I could split this into separate calls and let the web backend handle the parameter calls but this adds latency and there are possible concurrency issues if this latency becomes large so I prefer to have the server run both calls asap.

Comment: I do not see you using the @SponsorID parameter.  Where would you use this?

Comment: `OUTPUT` parameter. But for fetching `AD.ADID` do you really need a procedure

Comment: you have an `ORDER BY` in your Update Statement??

Comment: The order by should have been in the select and I forgot to include the @sponsorID parameter. Thank you for the suggestions.
Fireblade, could you explain what you mean by output parameter? The database will be accessed by web methods and an eventual API so I would prefer to use stored procs.

Comment: you need to declare the `@ADID` parameter first and then when you're doing the top 1, just set the @ADID parameter. so the select should look like `SELECT TOP 1
  @ADID = AD.ADID FROM Sponsors.AD
WHERE AD.Active = 1
ORDER BY NEWID()` and then use it to update the record. i don't see a need to call another stored procedure for an update statement unless its doing some extra stuff.

Comment: It is doing extra stuff; I just didn't want to include it because it is irrelevant to the problem at hand but thanks! I'm gonna try that and see if it works!

Comment: great. you can call the update procedure like `EXEC SPR_UPDATEROW @ADID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated above, you would first need to declare @ADID - something like:

```
DECLARE @ADID INT;
```

Once you've done that, select the ID you want into it:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @ADID = AD.ADID
FROM Sponsors.AD
WHERE AD.Active = 1 and AD.Sponsor = @SponsorID
```

Then you can conditionally start your process:

```
IF ISNULL(@ADID,-1) != -1
BEGIN 
 EXEC YourStoredProc @ADID
END
```

To return the ID at the end, just do:

```
SELECT @ADID AS ADID;
```

You could instead use the output parameter method by declaring the output variable with your procedure:

```
CREATE PROC Sponsors.GetLightBoxAds (
@SponsorID varchar(30),
@ADIDOut INT OUTPUT
)
AS --...
```

Then do:

```
SELECT @ADIDOut = @ADID;
```

Comment: I ended up with something similar to this with one exception. I am trying to use the return statement for the output instead of OUTPUT but even though ADID is a varchar and I declare @ADID as a varchar in the proc when I run the procedure I get the int value [instead of '00005' I get '5'. Is this because I'm using return instead of your way?

Comment: Using return with a declared output parameter should work together (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  This sounds more like the ADID value is getting converted between numeric and character somewhere in the chain of events and losing its leading zeros in the process.  But I don't know what your underlying data looks like, so that is just a guess.